# How to scale an image with the size of a bitmap in RecylerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have taken a picture from camera and now I want to add it in a `RecyclerView`, but when I start to scale that bitmap with the size of the ImageView `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` always zero and gives me an arithmetic exception.

Here is how I am doing this in the `onBindViewHolder()` method

```
        int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/five_dp">

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/ivMessage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/hundread_twenty_dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/hundread_twenty_dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_white"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/kutumbita_with_logo" />

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/ivMenu"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/thirty_five_dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/thirty_five_dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivMessage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_autorenew_black_24dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But my targetW and targetH is always zero.

Comment: Please post the Layout XML that contains the ImageView

Comment: @ItamarKerbel I have edited the question please look

Comment: You get 0 from width and height of the ImageView because it is empty by the time you fetch it.

Comment: You have `@dimen/hundread_twenty_dp` and `@dimen/thirty_five_dp`, so why don't you just use that directly to resize your bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the width and height of the ImageView before it is actually rendered. This is why the result is zero.

Possible solution is to use post method. It will be called after the view has calculated dimensions:

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //get width and height, scale bitmap etc.
            }
        })
```